# Why do I get "Theme hook ... not found" after renaming?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a module to create and handle surveys. I made a theme originally for it called "survey" and everything worked fine. I am now trying to rename the theme/template to "questionList", but am getting "Theme hook questionList not found" in the logs.

My working code with the theme name "survey" is shown below.

#### survey.module

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function survey_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $variables = array(
        'survey' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'questions'    => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $variables;
}
```

#### RadioQuestionController.php

```
    public function getAllQuestions()
    {
        $element['#questions'] = array(1,2,3,4,5);

        $element['#title'] = 'Radio Questions';
        $element['#theme'] = 'survey';
        return $element;
    }
```

#### survey.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to print list of questions.
 *
 * Available variables:
 *   - questions
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<h1>Test</h1>
```

The above works fine and prints "Test" to the specified path in my .routing.yml file. However the following does not work.

#### survey.module

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function questionList_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $variables = array(
        'questionList' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'questions'    => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $variables;
}
```

#### RadioQuestionController.php

```
    public function getAllQuestions()
    {
        $element['#questions'] = array(1,2,3,4,5);

        $element['#title'] = 'Radio Questions';
        $element['#theme'] = 'questionList';
        return $element;
    }
```

#### questionList.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to print list of questions.
 *
 * Available variables:
 *   - questions
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Is there something that I am missing that I need to change other than what is changed in the above code? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Try to clear cache or disable and then re enable the theme again. Clearing a cache is required most of the times if you make a change to a theme or module in Drupal.

Comment: Lowercase the "L".

Answer (score 1):

```
function questionList_theme(...)
```

must have the name of the module, like :

```
function survey_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $variables = array(
        'questionList' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'questions'    => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $variables;
}
```

will work.